# 'cannot be assigned to -- is read only' yet has a setter?

Tags: c#, prism

I'm getting a (to me) very weird looking argument exception.

When calling `this.MainViewModel.MyObject = new MyObject(..some parameters here..);`, I get `property or indexer 'IMainViewModel.MyObject' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`. I've been trying to find people with similar questions but everytime the answer is 'do you have a setter?'. Yes, I do have a setter. Yes, my property is public. I'm very confused as to why it is throwing a fit here.

The property I'm trying to write to is;

```
public Object MyObject
{
    get { return this.myObject; }
    set
    {
        this.myObject = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<SetMyObjectEvent>().Publish(this.MyObject);
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing that qualifies the MyObject property as readonly .. ?

Comment: Does the interface contains a setter? Looks like the object is casted to it's interface.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I'm going to jump out the window here.. You're spot on. Completely forgot about the bloody interface..

Comment: Such a peccadillo does not mandate autodefenestration. ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson it does make me feel really dumb for overlooking something so obvious :^)