# Disabling my TabItem during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following xaml code;

```
<TabControl Grid.Colum="2" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

In my CodeBegind file (.xalm.cs) I have my viewmodel bound as datacontext (working with MVVM) and I have the title set like this;

```
public string title { get { return "MyTabName"; } }
```

In my viewmodel I have the following property set up;

```
private bool isEnabled

public bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return this.isEnabled; }
    set
    {
        this.isEnabled = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**Problem:** The problem is the binding not working. I do know the binding is set-up properly, because I have a button on the same page on the same binding; `IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"`, so I suppose my problem has to do with the `<Setter/>` only being called once upon generating the view, but because the TabControl has an x amount of tabs, depending on how much views are loaded from the prism:RegionManager, it has to be dynamic and can't be set to individual `TabItem`s.

**Question:** My concrete question here is, **How do I set the `IsEnabled` property for all the `TabItem`s with the abovementioned binding?**

**In Addition:** I have tried

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
```

Which did indeed disables the `TabItem`s, which is why I'm convinced the `<Setter/>` is only called upon first-time generating the view and the problem is not with the binding.

Comment: Why don't you just set `IsEnabled` in the `TabControl` itself?  Or am I not understanding?

Comment: @rory.ap That is exactly what I wanted.. You do not want to know the amount of shit I've tried to put in that `<Setter/>` property, only to throw it on SO and have an answer in under 5 minutes.. I guess it's going to be [autodefenestration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450154/cannot-be-assigned-to-is-read-only-yet-has-a-setter?noredirect=1#comment66221601_39450154) anyway ..